# IronBarCode stream only

Tags: c#, ironbarcode

I want to create an QrCode using IronBarCode, and then save it as a Stream or Byte[].
However both methods expect the file to be saved prior to creation:

```
            var absolute = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + url;
            var qrcode = IronBarCode.QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(absolute);
            qrcode.AddAnnotationTextAboveBarcode(device.Name);
            qrcode.AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode(absolute);
            var f = qrcode.ToJpegStream();
            var y = qrcode.ToJpegBinaryData();
```

ToJpegStream() and ToJpegBinaryData expects the absolute string to be an actual file path.  I want to create a QrCode and save it as a Byte[] or Stream, however the error thrown is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Answer (score 2):

The issue mentioned isn't reproducible with the code provided. The code below is adapted from your code and the from the [example](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/examples/csharp-create-qr-code/). It's been tested.

**Create a new** `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)`

**Download/install NuGet package**: `Barcode`

**Add a Button to Form1** (name: btnCreateQRCode)

**Add a PictureBox to Form1** (name: pictureBox1)

[image]

**Add using directives**:

- `using IronBarCode;`
- `using System.IO;`

**Form1.cs**:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private byte[] _qrCode = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private byte[] CreateBarCode(string url, string annotationText)
    {
        //create new instance
        GeneratedBarcode qrCode = QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(url);
        qrCode.AddAnnotationTextAboveBarcode(annotationText);
        qrCode.AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode(url);

        byte[] qrCodeBytes = qrCode.ToJpegBinaryData();

        return qrCodeBytes;
    }

    private void btnCreateQRCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _qrCode = CreateBarCode("https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+search", "How To Search");

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_qrCode))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; //fit to size
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Resources**:

- [Create QR Code](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/examples/csharp-create-qr-code/)

Answer (score 1):

`AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode` method parameter for string is `FontPath`. That is why it was trying to find the font file that does not exist.

```cs
string absolute = "https://ironsoftware.com/";
string Name = "Product URL:";

//Add Annotation(text) below the generated barcode
var qrcode = QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(absolute);
qrcode.AddAnnotationTextBelowBarcode(Name);
qrcode.ToJpegBinaryData();

//Add Barcode value below the generated barcode
var qrcode = QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(absolute);
qrcode.AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode();
qrcode.ToJpegBinaryData();
```

The below image is `FontPath`. `FontPath` is actually the directory path that actually lead to the Font file.

[image]

```cs
//This will add Barcode value into QRCode
.AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode()
```

If you want to add absolute path to the QRCode you should use

```cs
//This will add your text to Barcode
.AddAnnotationTextBelowBarcode(absolute)
```

For more information on how to use the method please refer to the API reference:
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/IronBarCode.GeneratedBarcode.html#IronBarCode_GeneratedBarcode_AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode