# When I am trying to generate QR code from web api in c# using QRCoder Package I cannot find QRCode in QRCode namespace in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code

When I am trying to generate a QR code from a web API in C# using QRCoder Package I cannot find QRCode in QRCode namespace in .NET 6

```
try
{
    //var res = awfait _qrGaneraterRepository.QRCodeGenerator(employeeSalaryGetId);

    QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGenerator.CreateQrCode(EmployeeSalaryGetId, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
    QRCode qrCoder = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
    //using (QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData))
    //{
    //    Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
    //}

    Image rqCodeImage = qrCoder.GetGraphic(20);

    var bytes = ImageToByteArray(rqCodeImage);
    return File(bytes, "image/tmp");

    //return res.Status ? StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, res) : StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, res);
}
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form.  Read [ask] and have someone proofread your question.  Then edit it into an acceptable form.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206917/how-to-generate-pdf-one-page-one-row-from-datatable-using-itextsharp/69218085#69218085 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352439/ironbarcode-stream-only/74353057#74353057

Comment: What `QRCoder package` are you talking about?

Comment: [This QRCoder package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/) was published a year ago and didn't change namespaces. Either you miss the package reference entirely or you're missing the `using QRCoder;` statement

Comment: If you can't get this to work, consider using the LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK, which support QR and many other types of barcodes, and is confirmed compatible with .NET 6. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor). There's [a .NET 6 tutorial here](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/dotnet-console-write-1d-and-2d-barcodes-to-an-image.html). If you would like to try it, there's [a free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: There's a **known "issue"** with qrcoder 1.4.3 in that it removes support for System.Drawing which was deprecated in net core 7.   One solution, if you're using *windows* is to use qrcoder 1.42.  See: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/issues/174

Answer (score 7):

Just downgrade to version 1.4.1
I had the same issue when using 1.4.3
This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Downgrade from 1.4.3 to 1.4.2 also solved my problem in ASP.NET Core WEB API on .NET 8.0

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much for posting. Even ChatGPT was stumped.